# Solving Poisson-like PDE with FFT

Tags: poisson, fourier-transform, spectral-method

**Problem**

I have an $n\times n$ grid, and each point on the grid is assigned two values: a score, and an (inverse) speed factor. There is a "turtle" moving along the grid, and it's goal is to maximize it's score. Each time it moves to a point $x$ it gets the score $s_x$ at that point, but it takes $\epsilon_x$ turns before it can move again. The turtle can only move in the four cardinal directions (north, east, south, west) and in the "center" direction (remaining where it currently is).

I want to assign a third value $p_x$, the "potential" at $x$, which helps the turtle find an optimal spot to move to. If the grid were extended to be continuous, the potential function should be continuous with a first derivative (or gradient).

---

**Preliminaries**

A natural choice for the potential function satisfies

$$\epsilon_xp_x = s_x + \frac{\sum\limits_{y\in \text{Neighbors}(x)}p_y}{4}\qquad (1)$$

(Notice that this almost exactly defines a qtable, except for the differing $\epsilon_x$ values.)

For now, assume that $\epsilon_x$ is constant. The equation happens to then be the same as a [Discrete Poisson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Poisson_equation). This means that physically $p_x$ is the potential field in a system where each point has a $-s_x$ charge on it. There are many ways to solve the Discrete Poisson equation, but one of the fastest is to use [spectral methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_method). See [here](https://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/neumann-cosine/) for using the Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT) to solve it. Our grid can be rather large ($50\times 50$), so to fit within a one-second time constraint we need an $O(n^2\log n)$ algorithm.

However, $\epsilon_x$ is not constant. $\epsilon_x$ physically represents the electric permittivity at the point $x$, so if it were a one dimensional grid we could set every $\epsilon_x$ to $1$ and insert points to mimic having a higher permittivity. However, we are on a two dimensional grid. Not only that, but $\epsilon_x$ is not necessarily an integer—it could be any positive real number. My goal is to use spectral analysis to solve  equation $(1)$ with an algorithm running in $O(n^2\log n)$ time.

---

**Progress**

First, rearrange the original equation:

$$\frac{p_{i+1,j}+p_{i-1,j}+p_{i,j+1}+p_{i,j01}}{4}-p_{i,j} + \gamma_{i,j}p_{i,j} = -s_{i,j}\qquad (2)$$
where $\gamma_{i,j} = 1-\epsilon_{i,j}$.

Notice that this is the finite difference equation for

$$\nabla^2 p + \gamma p = -s\qquad (3)$$

Now,
$$\nabla^2(fp) = f\nabla^2p + 2\nabla f\cdot\nabla p + p\nabla^2f$$
so if I can find a function $f$ that satisfies
$$2\nabla f\cdot\nabla p = 0, \frac{\nabla^2 f}{f} = \gamma$$
I would be mostly done. I just solve the Poisson equation $\nabla^2(fp) = -fs$ and divide by $f$. However, I don't know how to do this in $O(n^2\log n)$ time.

Alternatively, we can go straight to spectral analysis. Let
$$p = \sum \hat{p}_{j,k}e^{i(jx+ky)}$$
$$s = \sum \hat{s}_{j,k}e^{i(jx+by)}$$

Plugging this into $(3)$ we get

$$\sum -\hat{p}_{j, k}(j^2+k^2)e^{i(jx+by)} + \gamma\sum \hat{p}_{j, k}e^{i(jx+ky)} = -\sum \hat{s}_{j, k}e^{i(jx+ky)}$$

Removing the summation yields
$$\hat{p}_{j,k}(j^2+k^2-\gamma) = \hat{s}_{j, k}\implies \hat{p}_{j,k} = \frac{\hat{s}_{j,k}}{j^2+k^2-\gamma}$$

But $\hat{p}_{j,k}, \hat{s}_{j,k}$ are constants while $\gamma$ is not, so there is no solution.

---

[Possible Duplicate?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28666/fft-poisson-solver-for-non-uniform-grid)

Comment: Spectral methods are best suited for linear problems with constant coefficients. If there is a spatially dependent coefficient then you could use spectral methods by expanding this coefficient in a Fourier series and then use convolutions but that's a pain. However, Eq. (2) is a five-diagonal linear system, and I thought for those the scaling of operation count is linear with the size, e.g., see discussion in https://www.12000.org/my_notes/penta_diagonal_solver_in_matlab/index.htm

Comment: I think you lack boundary conditions.

Comment: I'm using Neumann boundary conditions.

Comment: @MaximUmansky that looks promising, but eq. (2) has diagonals that aren't all in one band. [This answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/30072/ways-to-solve-ax-b-for-a-sparse-banded-a-with-updates) has more info on solving this specific problem. I'll look into it.

Comment: I looked into [solving outrigger systems](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/2/2.086/S13/MIT2_086S13_Unit5_Textbook.pdf), and for my particular equation it would run in $O(n^3)$ time. It *might* be fast enough, but I would prefer an $O(n^2\log n)$ algorithm if I can find one.

Comment: Aha! I found a paper with what I need:
https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02010640/document. Except it uses the GMRES method, which is iterative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an iterative method to find $p$. Do the following steps:

1. Solve the equation $\nabla^2 p^1 = -s$.
2. Solve the new equation $\nabla^2 p^{n+1} = -(s+\gamma p^n)$.
3. Repeat step 2 until convergence.

Assuming you use the [DCT method](https://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/neumann-cosine/) you linked to solve the Poisson equations, then steps 1 and 2 only take $O(n^2\log n)$ time. The convergence rate of step 3 is exponential, so very few iterations are needed.

### [image: Errors for a 50x50 grid.]

The trickiest part is finding the convergence rate. Looking at the DCT method in that link, step 2 involves finding

$$\hat{p^{n+1}}_{x,y} = -\frac{\hat{f^n}_{x,y}}{2(C_x + C_y - 2)}$$

where $\hat{f^n}_{x, y}$ represents a coefficient in the DCT of $s+\gamma p^n$. Let $r(x,y) = -2(C_x + C_y - 2)$, and $\hat{p^n} = \hat{p} + \delta^n$ where $\hat{p}$ is the true solution. As the DCT is additive, and multiplication in real space corresponds to a convolution in Fourier space, we get

\begin{align*}
\hat{p^{n+1}} &= \frac{\hat{s} + \hat{\gamma}*\hat{p^n}}{r}\\
&=\frac{\hat{s}+ \hat{\gamma}*\hat{p} + \hat{\gamma}*\delta^n}{r}
\end{align*}

The true solution satisfies

$$\hat{p} = \frac{\hat{s}+ \hat{\gamma}*\hat{p}}{r}$$

so

\begin{align*}
\delta^{n+1} &= \frac{\hat{s}+ \hat{\gamma}*\hat{p} + \hat{\gamma}*\delta^n}{r} - \frac{\hat{s}+ \hat{\gamma}*\hat{p}}{r}\\
&= \frac{\hat{\gamma}*\delta^n}{r}
\end{align*}

Let $||x||$ represent the 1-norm of $x$, and $m=\min(|r(x)|)$. From [Young's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality),

$$\lVert r\delta^n\rVert = \lVert\hat{\gamma}*\delta^n\rVert \le \lVert\hat{\gamma}\rVert\lVert\delta^n\rVert\le \frac{\lVert\hat{\gamma}\rVert}{m}\lVert r\delta^n\rVert$$

Therefore the method converges exponentially. Unfortunately this implies that unless $\hat{\gamma}$ is not close to $1$, it won't converge.

Comment: I noticed you are using fixed point iteration, which doesn't have the quickest convergence rate (or may not converge at all if $\lVert \hat{\gamma}\rVert > m$). You can speed this up using a quasi-Newton method. See [Woodbury's matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity#Inverse_of_a_sum).